# Set-Cookie directive in Electron.js not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise, electron

I have a problem. In my Electron app I have a login form. On form submit I fetch a Rails Devise based auth server, which completes and responds with Set-cookie direction < app_name>-main_session

In my electron main process I have the response with working cookies, but they are not set and I can't set them manually (for security reasons).

I'd like to use https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/cookies.md to set my session cookie. But I can't.

Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you're running into problems with security protocols in place to keep session information private. You'll need to change your methods one way or the other.

You'll need to choose one of two approaches for this:

- Treat your rails app as a pure API, in which case you'd use something link a JSON Web Token or custom API key sent with each request. This works best if you're generating views from electron itself.
- Execute all your actions within the context of a Webview, which goes through the normal devise authentication flow. This works well if you're basically just using electron as a shell around server render views.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel for your fast answer. My rails app has already custom api responses with json and jwt. How do I manage logins and cookies? Thank you very much!